# Is there another way of linking a submit button in a form to another page without using action attribute?

Tags: action, github-pages, form-submit, submit-button

I developed a website that contains submit buttons that are linked to other pages on my website. I used the action attribute for the links, but it happens that GitHub doesn't support action attributes (HTTP). Is there another way that I can link my submit buttons to other pages but without using the action attribute? Note: the submit button should be inside a form.

```
<form method="POST" action="../pages/home2.html" target="_self">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username here" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Whenever I click to submit, a 405 problem occurs (not allowed). Help appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at using AJAX to submit the form?

Comment: Why do you want to send `POST` request to a simple HTML page? Who/what is reading the post data? Does it work when you use `GET` instead?

Comment: Harrison, Progman, thank you for your response.  I'm still a beginner and this is just an example of my form. Anyway, I have just known that GitHub doesn't support method POST or GET, so what I did is that I deleted the method attribute and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I finally knew what was the problem. Github happens not to support method="POST" (HTTP), so what I did is that I deleted the method attribute and everything works fine now. Although my form works as if the method attribute is set to GET, because data inserted appears in the url above my website. And the code above is just a simple example of my real form. This is my simple website https://aghbary.github.io/YemeniHtml/

Thanks..

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).